# Issues with css in jar created out of gwt project

Tags: java, gwt, jar, packaging

I have created a jar of a gwt project but when using it in the other project the css does not reflect.

the structure of jar is as follows
-com
 -trial
    -Trial.java
    -Trial.class
 -trial.xml
 -public
    -trial.css
-META-INF
 -MANIFEST.MF

Please guide me here as to where I am wrong and how can I get the css working..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "css does not reflect"? CSS may be obfuscated during GWT compilation, so maybe that's why you cannot refer to some class defined within it (if that's the case).